# Entity Framework Core: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have a middleware component and I try to get some data from my database. But some requests throw an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed.

I already have:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Database.DatabaseContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

in my dependency injection. Any ideas about possible error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I forget about the middleware lifetime. Is a Singelton, and i try to get my database context in middleware constructor:

```
public SessionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        ILogger<SessionMiddleware> logger,
        DatabaseContext databaseContext)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        _context = databaseContext;
    }
```

Right way to get database context - get it in the `InvokeAsync`

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext content, DatabaseContext _context)
```

With this way we will be recive a new object every time.

Sorry for my English

Comment: You should remove `ServiceLifetime.Transient` too. The default, scoped, ensures the DbContext is disposed after every request. In ASP.NET Core, the DI scope is the request